# Ruby on Rails => Server is sleeping before some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, redmine

I have installed Redmine on my computer, i can run it with the command:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

And that's working good

But it's just for work with localhost.
I need to access to Redmine from another station. For this, i have found this command:

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

And that's working good, but in this case, after some time without query, the rail server turn in sleep.
And if i clic in redmine, the server don't response. I have to enter in console and press a key for wake up it.

Comment: What you probally want is something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which sets up a tunnel to localhost. You'll also want a "real" rails server like Puma - Webrick is a development server and is no longer the default.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I'm running Windows 10.
I saw nGrok in another article, but i just want see my server in my LAN, not from Internet, it seem too big (and too complcated) for my need.

Comment: Ok, i tried ngrok, Indeed, it is quite simple. But i need to run 2 consoles each time (every day in my case) and moreover, it seem to generate a specific key at each run. I prefer acces to my computer with my ip (that i can configure to my wishes).
There isn't a solution with rails command ?
Is the standby behavior known?

Answer (score 0):

That's working with

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -p3000 -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

Thanks to MAX for telling me that WebRick was a webserver